# AddStyleSheet Error on Joomla 3.0

Tags: php, joomla-extensions, joomla3.1

I am getting the error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function addStyleSheet() on a non-object in /home/[hidden]/public_html/msa/templates/protostar/index.php on line 187
```

When I try to view only certain pages on my site. I am using Joomla 3.1.5 and this is my template code:

```
<?php defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<!-- Include Joomla Header -->
<jdoc:include type="head" />
<!-- Get page title -->
<?php $article = JTable::getInstance("content"); $article->load(JRequest::getInt("id")); $pageTitle = $article->get("title"); ?>
<!-- Open Graph -->
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $pageTitle; ?>"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content=""/>
<!-- Google Analytics + Webmaster -->
<!-- CSS --->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/templates/[hidden]/css/responsive-grid.css" media="screen, print, handheld" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/templates/[hidden]/css/style.css" media="screen, print, handheld" />
<?php

$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addStyleSheet('templates/[hidden]/style.css');
$document->addStyleSheet(JUri::base().'templates/[hidden]/css/style.css');

JHtml::stylesheet('templates/[hidden]/css/style.css');
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much deliberation and hunting I found this error was being cause because my template was not set as default. Not sure why it only occurred on some pages but setting the template to default fixed this.